# Regression following Principal Component Analysis

Tags: r, regression, pca

I am not sure if i did not add enough information or i am posting to the wrong section but if i am please let me know as it is my first time using the site.
I have carried out Principal Component Analysis on my dataset and have reduced my dimensions. I would like to run some basic regressions using the first two components as explanatory variables.
Does anyone know how I would do this and what code I would need to use.
I am not the greatest on R as you may tell so any help anyone can provide would be gratefully appreciated.
One of the replies had suggested using prcomp but as i used a correlation matrix and the princomp command would that still be appropriate?

```
pro1.pca <- princomp(pro1,cor = T)
k <- 4
pro1.scores <- pro1.pca$scores[,1:k]
    round(pro1.pca$loadings[,1:k],3) 
    ##                          Comp.1     Comp.2    Comp.3     Comp.4 
    ## Hazardous Drinker         0.292     0.381     0.423      0.478 
    ## Cardiovascular Condition -0.351    -0.238     0.599     -0.350 
    ## Fruit + Veg-5 or more     0.444    -0.039     0.139     -0.558 
    ## General Health Score 4+  -0.099     0.603     0.350     -0.148 
    ## Obese                    -0.457    -0.131    -0.196      0.281 
    ## health- very good         0.357    -0.289     0.273      0.461 
    ## Current Smoker           -0.133     0.576    -0.294     -0.048 
    ## Meets Activity Levels:    0.480     0.005    -0.348     -0.149
```

Comment: You've got a mix of variables that loosely measure some factors that connote or promote health and others  that don't. By and large, I'd expect two clusters of variables, the clusters being negatively correlated with each other. But your first two PCs (any two PCs!) are by construction uncorrelated. If parsimony is the goal using two variables as predictors -- just possibly one from each cluster -- is likely to be **much** easier to interpret.

Comment: This was closed as being in effect a request for coding help. See advice in the Help Center on software-specific questions. You could try making the question more statistical, but my guess is that you'd need to say much more about your data (e.g. what is the outcome or response variable; the sample size; are these cross-sectional data or panel data) to have a good chance of getting this re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

You did not share any data but this example may be useful. First code the PCA, then store the components in a new dataframe. After that, bind components with original data and then design the linear model. Here the code uses only `base-R` and example data `iris`:

```
#Data
data(iris)
#PCA
pcamod <- prcomp(iris[,-5],scale. = T)
#Extract components
comp <- as.data.frame(pcamod$x)
#Create dataframe for regression
newdata <- cbind(iris[,-5],comp)
#linear model
mod <- lm(Sepal.Length~PC1+PC2,data=newdata)
summary(mod)
```

Output:

```
summary(mod)

Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ PC1 + PC2, data = newdata)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.61478 -0.12606 -0.00421  0.15399  0.48173 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  5.84333    0.01894  308.56   <2e-16 ***
PC1          0.43148    0.01112   38.79   <2e-16 ***
PC2         -0.31253    0.01987  -15.72   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2319 on 147 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9226,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9215 
F-statistic: 876.1 on 2 and 147 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```